# How to put key value pair into map with variable key name

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to end up with a single map containing many different preferences, it should look like this:

```
%{some_preference_name:%{foo:"bar"},another_preference_name:%{foo:"bar"}}
```

I have a list of preference maps from the database, and I need to get through them and set the "preference" field as the key with the various values as the values map.

I tried to do this with Enum.reduce and Enum,map, but I can't get the list right.

```
Enum.map(preferences, fn(data)->
  Map.put(%{}, data.preference,
   %{
     foo: data.foo
    }
  )
end)
```

returns:

```
[{some_preference_name:%{foo:"bar"}},{another_preference_name:%{foo:"bar"}}]
```

then:

```
Enum.reduce(preferences, fn(acc, data)->
  Map.put(acc, data.preference,
   %{
     foo: data.foo
    }
  )
end)
```

returns:

```
%{some_preference_name:%{foo:"bar"},preference: "another_preference_name",foo:"bar"}
```

It gets the first one right, but not the rest.  I understand that as of Erlang R17, the only way I will be able to add a variable key name is with Map.put/3.

Comment: Please provide your list of preference maps from the database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you have just swapped the arguments order in the reduce function:

```
Enum.reduce(preferences, fn(data, acc)->
  Map.put(acc, data.preference, %{foo: data.foo})
end)
```

Comment: Ended up using Enum/reduce/3 instead in order to fill the empty map instead of the first preference, although Arkar Aung's solution worked too :-). I do not know how I mixed those up.  BTW, is this just preferred because it is easier to read?

Comment: It is preferred because it is easier to read, in my opinion, and it can work with many data structures too.

Answer (score 15):

You can now (since `Elixir 1.2.0`) do it without any hacks.
This is listed in the language improvements section in [the changes overview](http://elixir-lang.org/blog/2016/01/03/elixir-v1-2-0-released/).

That is how to do it:

```
iex> key = :hello
iex> value = "world"
iex> %{key => value}
%{:hello => "world"}
```

And if you want to pattern match an existing variable - use `^` operator:

```
iex> key = :hello
iex> %{^key => value} = %{:hello => "another world"}
iex> value
"another world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `hd()` and `tl()` with recursion to get list item instead of `Enum.map` and `Enum.reduce` .

```
def get_preference() do
    preferences = [%{:preference => "some_preference_name", :foo => "bar"}, %{:preference => "another_preference_name", :foo => "rab"}]
    convert(preferences, %{})
end

def convert([], map) do
    map
end

def convert([head|tail], map) do
    map = Map.put(map, head.preference, %{foo: head.foo})
    convert(tail, map)
end
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: `Enum.reduce/3` and `Enum.map/2` are usually preferred. Your example could also be improved by pattern matching on the last convert clause (`convert([h|t], map)` instead of explicitly calling `hd` and `tl`).